# Whether to use MEAN.js or not?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack, meanjs

What advantages we will get if we use MEAN.js framework over our homegrown MEAN packaging? we are not going to use angular.js (A part of MEAN.js)
Will we face any API versioning issues? Will there be any issues related versioning of packages in MEAN?
Is it really complex to use MEAN.js as compared to creating own structure to use manage APIs, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to create custom MEAN stack myself, but it was only a matter of time when i realized, that MEAN is not only MongoDB, Express, Angular and Node. Just look at node modules to see how many additional things there are. Authorization(passport.js), connectors, parsers, test libraries, mailer, promieses, etc. When i was starting I didn't find these tools useful, but now I would add most of them to my custom MEAN. Thats why I use MEAN.js stack

Answer (score 0):

We can't possibly know whether your configuration will work better than MEAN.js because we know neither your needs, nor your configuration. MEAN.js provides an API out-of-the-box and supports scaffolding (via [yeoman](http://yeoman.io)) which generates files and code with a single command. I am not a huge framework enthusiast in general, but I have to admit that development became much more easier and enjoyable since we switched to MEAN.js (ditching our own custom MEAN stack).

Comment: I agree, especially the integration with passport.js and user management modules which are provided out of box by MEAN.js are really helpful